# Como puedo ordenar un array de objetos . Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

Tengo una respuesta JSON (Array de objetos) que contiene: Latitud y Longitud.
Como puedo ordenar esos objetos de mayor a menor distancia con respecto a la ubicacion actual del dispositivo.

ejemplo de respuesta Json :

```
[
    {
        "PlaceId": "ChIJjS5n_YLMj4ARlfgRtxtoW00",
        "PlaceName": "IHOP",
        "Address": "644 N 1st St, San Jose",
        "Category": "restaurant",
        "IsOpenNow": "Open now",
        "Latitude": 37.348115,
        "Longitude": -121.8990835,
        "Thumbnail": "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=2400&photoreference=CmRaAAAAe8OYJqvYpTKJR3EkuxBukX1ox0gm9-8NNO19OvbCRtiSvKHthC_3_8KAsq6-ARBRR1T-zzigB8k8THFVAQsYTJD3ibe_LE_Cwi4whBVkKBhO6R-HQIpKpFYVcDAq3rEoEhANPd06Rb2KwWN3HGJ0rVBhGhRLWqZY9nHwHf7tCRSMjiYtmeD1Lw&key=AIzaSyBKYncKJA-Uu060807q_t3g1Y6o6Y9fyaI",
        "Rating": 4.2,
        "IsPetFriendly": false,
        "AddressLine1": "644 N 1st St",
        "AddressLine2": "San Jose",
        "PhoneNumber": "(664) 326 2312",
        "Site": "http://www.arkusnexus.com"
    }
]

la peticion esta hecha con Alamofire:

[![peticion get][1]][1]
```

implementacion de la respuesta en ViewController:

```
  NetworkingProvider.shared.GetPlaces { places in

                    self.places.append(contentsOf: places)

                } failure: { error in
                    print(error.debugDescription)
                }
```

llenado delas celdas del tableView:

```
Swift

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? CustomCell else{
            return UITableViewCell()
        }

        if !self.places.isEmpty{
            let place = self.places[indexPath.row]
            cell.fillCell(item: place)
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Te faltaría la función para calcular la distancia. Al recorrer el array de objetos comparas las distancias y almacenas ese valor en cada objeto y al final con `sorted` lo  ordenas.